# If I root a Droid ( Razr M) does it get factory reset (erasing all installed apps, etc.)?

Tags: rooting, motorola-droid-razr

I'm considering [rooting my Razr M](http://www.droid-life.com/2013/04/09/root-method-released-for-droid-razr-hd-running-android-4-1-2-other-devices-too/).

If I do that but don't install an alternate ROM, will this erase anything on my phone or simply "unlock it"?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to unlock the bootloader first (I could not find that in the instructions; you might check the script for the term `oem unlock`, usually done via `fastboot`), this includes a [factory-reset](/questions/tagged/factory-reset), which would mean "all clean up delete", i.e. all data and your self-installed apps would be gone.

Otherwise, if no bootloader-unlock is involved, the rooting process itself would usually not delete anything.